# ClassCastException When converting Collection to array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections

For a project of mine i'm trying to convert a given Collection to an array

I currently have this:

```
public class InsertionSorter< T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T[] array;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public InsertionSorter(){
        array = (T[]) new Object[0];
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.base/[Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

Is there a solution for this?

And after i converted it to an array i want to to sort it and return it back as an collection. I do this as following:

```
collection.clear();
collection.addAll(Arrays.asList(sort(array)));
return collection;
```

The sort method is a method which sorts an array and returns an array of type T.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you understand that Object is not same as array? Why not Object array instead of T?

Comment: In essential i want to convert a Collection of type T to an array of type T

Comment: Use object array in that case... T is just provides compile type safety and not runtime...

Comment: @SMA, Object array won't do. you will not be able to invoke `compareTo()` on items in the array

Comment: Oh sorry for not being specific. After i changed it to an array i want to return it again as a collection after i sorted the array. Im gonna edit the post a little bit.

Comment: Duplicate of what other post? I couldnt find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Your typedefinition `T` claims that instances will be at least `Comparable`, but then you try to assign an array of `Object`, which is *not* `Comparable`, thus resulting in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: this may provide an answer as to why the exception occurs but no solution